# How to extend importHTML functions further

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import

Is it possible to join two query to shape data from a importHTML function?

Currently I have imported one column with 40 rows each cell has 3 lines of text, I need them to have their own columns but the 3 text line is not required. (Record Label)

1. To split 3 lines of text within a cell and transpose them into their own columns. The third line of text is not required therefore
   Could be deleted. The following formula I have used locally on GS.

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A1:A),split(A1:A,char(10)),))
```

With success.Unable to work out how to translate this array into the importHTML

[Shows my GS layout with importHTML formula divided into 4 segments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLuOp.jpg)

2. There are also blanks generated and is there a formula to join with the above array?

[Shows the array that splits the three lines of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SODyV.jpg)

Comment: Can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you need?

Try this in cell `B5`.

`=arrayformula(query(split(query(importhtml(B1,B2,B3),"select Col3 where Col3 is not null",1),char(10)),"select Col1,Col2 order by Col1,Col2 label Col1 'Song', Col2 'Artist'",1))`

Method:

`importhtml(B1,B2,B3)` brings in the data where B1, B2 and B3 are your cells containing URL, query item and index.

`query(importhtml(B1,B2,B3),"select Col3 where Col3 is not null",1)` is a `QUERY` function used to only select col 3 of the data.

`SPLIT` then splits each cell value into separate columns, based on a line return `char(10)`. There are 3 columns.

Another `QUERY` around this selects only Col1 and Col2, and orders the result by Col1 then Col2, and then names the head of Col1 'Song' and Col2 'Artist'.

`ARRAYFORMULA` sits on the outside and ensures that all subsequent row data is processed, provided that the functions inside are compatible (mainly for the `SPLIT` function).

For more info on `QUERY` see Google's reference here:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, removed the spaces at the same time. Would you have any links to resources in this area. Going to learn so much from your formula.

Comment: Happy to help :-) `QUERY` is very useful.  I've updated the solution, with method notes (and moved `ARRAYFORMULA` to the outside of the formula, since it's better there).

Comment: That was very good of you to explain. Thanks for the google ref.